# Dynamic Programming: Vertex Cover of simple graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

I am looking to find an efficient algorithm to find the min-cost vertex cover of two specific graphs where vertices have varying cost.

The first graph is a linked list of sorts, in which we have V={1...n} and E={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}...{n-1,n}}

The second graph is a simple cycle. Basically the same as above but with {n,1} being an edge as well.

I have figured out a way to do the first one recursively, by simply exhaustively checking whether each node should be in the vertex cover or not.

```
VC(Graph G(V,E)):
  if(|V|=0) return 0
  u=first node of V
  v=second node of V
  return min(VC(Graph.remove(u)+cost(u),   //Case where the first node is in VC
             VC(Graph.remove(v,u))+cost(v)) //Case where second node is in VC
```

Yet this is truly inefficient, is there a way to improve on this using dynamic programming?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the structure of those specific graphs? You will be in trouble otherwise..

Comment: yes! Most definitely. They only need to work for these graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a chain, dynamic programming solution is pretty straight-forward. The state is `(number of vertices processed, is the last vertex taken)`. The value of the state is the minimum cost to cover this part of the graph.
2. For a cycle, we can use the following observation: either the first or the second vertex is in the cover. So we can reduce it to the 1) problem  by removing the first or the second vertex and choosing the best answer.

Both of this solutions have linear time complexity.

Some pseudo code for the part 1:

```
f(1, false) = 0 // do not take the first vertex
f(1, true) = cost(1) // take it
for v <- 2 ... n:
    f(v, false) = f(v - 1, true) // do not take the current vertex
    f(v, true) = min(f(v - 1, true), f(v - 1, false)) + cost(v) // take it
print(min(f(n, false), f(n, true)))
```

Comment: This is really interesting.  Can you develop a little more on part 1?

Comment: Sweet! This is great!